# Passing string values into an array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm using following code to pass number values to my shopping cart cord.

```
if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
            echo   '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold">
                        <td>Serial</td>
                        <td>Part No</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Price</td>
                        <td>Qty</td>
                        <td>Amount</td>
                        <td>Options</td>
                    </tr>';


            $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
            for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                $pname=get_product_name($pid);
                if($q==0) continue;
        ?>
                <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <td><?php echo $i+1 ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pid ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pname ?></td>
                    <td>$ <?php echo get_price($pid)?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>                    
                    <td>$ <?php echo get_price($pid)*$q?></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:del(<? echo $pid?>)">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
        <?php                   
            }
        ?>
```

when I'm inserting number values like "12191008" , "05191034" it's working fine. but for the string values like "PF401404" its not working. how can I modify the code to pass string values ?

also add to cart function as follows..

```
function addtocart($pid,$q){
    if($pid<1 or $q<1) return;

    if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
        if(product_exists($pid)) return;
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][$max]['qty']=$q;
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['productid']=$pid;
        $_SESSION['cart'][0]['qty']=$q;
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you inserting it? what part of your code?

Comment: Which part you facing error. and why its not inserting any debug from your side? also tell us in which line its create issue.

Comment: value is taking from previous page. ($pid=$_REQUEST['productid'];
    addtocart($pid,1); ) I dont know from which part is the creating problem.

Comment: If your $pid is one of  "12191008" , "05191034", "PF401404"  ?

Comment: Yes. $pid is "PF401404"..

Comment: check string to int conversion manual : http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
if($pid<1 or $q<1) return;
```

this is not working for you. Because your $pid is not an integer in your case

Comment: Yes it is. how can I change this to string..?

Comment: first you just comment that line , then check is it working?

Comment: commented . it now it says "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ..etc" but for numbers the error does not appearing.

Comment: When you using string value where should  you get the error?